# What parts of speech are the words "pick up" when used as a verb

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I'm aware of the difference between "pick up" and "pickup" but what grammatical purpose do the individual words serve when separated? How would you distinguish between them or classify them if you were parsing them one word at a time? 
The words function as a single verb but "pick" functions as a verb by itself. I presume you would say that "up" modifies its' meaning.

The context is that I'm writing a parser to mimic the functionality of text based games like Zork. If you have any thoughts on the subject​, advice, or stumbling blocks to tell me about I would love to hear from you.

Comment: They don't function as a single word, but as two distinct words. "Pick"  is of course a verb, and "up" is a preposition.

Comment: Building on what @BillJ says, the preposition doesn't act as a 'modifier' on the verb but as a complement to it. And *pickup*, written as one word, is a noun.

Comment: On the grammar:  "pick up" is not a constituent at word level: it's a verb phrase. Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s just "pick" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have "He picked up Ed at 5" but not *"He pick upped Ed at 5".

Comment: @BillJ I'm with you as far as *up* being a preposition and the semantic category "particle" being a piece of academic makework. *Come pick me up* and *come pick me* are completely different concepts, though, and *pick up* is most certainly a single phrasal verb.

Comment: @lly I wouldn't call "up" a particle here, though it would be in "He picked Ed up" ~ "He picked up Ed".  But "pick up" is not a 'single verb'. Please see my last message.

Comment: Do you want to know about the idiom *pick up* as in *things are picking up*, or are you interested in the idiom *pick something up* as in *he picked up the pen*?

Comment: Either, I guess. I'm interested in how to distinguish between two words that serve a single purpose and are a single logical unit and one word that may or may not stand alone. I was originally thinking of picking up pens though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Pick up the pen.
> 2. Pick the pen up.
> 3. Pick it up.
> 4. *Pick up it. (ungrammatical)

The idiomatic string *pick up* is often described as a *separable phrasal verb* (I don't believe in phrasal verbs so I don't use this term). As shown in examples (1-4) the Direct Object of the verb *pick* can go either before or after the word *up*—unless it is a pronoun, in which case it must go before it.

Because the word *up* can appear without a following noun phrase in such idioms, it has often been regarded an adverb here. In most (but not all) modern grammars, however, words like *up* are classified as prepositions, whether or not they take a noun phrase as a Complement (in the same way that verbs are still regarded as verbs whether or not they take a Direct Object). In grammars such as *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts (2011), for example, the word *up* would be classified as a preposition here.

All the evidence indeed seems to show that words like *up* in this example are prepositions and not adverbs. For example, *up* can be modified by the specialised adverb *right* which modifies prepositions, but not adverbs:

- He pick it right up, and ran out of the door.

Unlike adverbs, which are usually modifiable by the word *very*, the word *up* cannot be modified by *very* (and note that *up*-ness has degrees, it is semantically gradable):

- *He picked it very up, and ran out of the door. (ungrammatical)

The verb *pick*, of course, remains a verb—whether or not it is used in  idiomatic verb-preposition combinations.

---

<sup>Bert Capelle classifies words like *up* here as a completely different part of speech, for which he uses the term *particle*. Note that this is not how other writers use the word. He does not argue that such words are adverbs.</sup>

Comment: You have an excellent point regarding noun and pronoun relations here. Do you have any thoughts on how to derive meaning from a mixed order here?

Comment: Strictly speaking, *up* in this example 'is' a preposition only by word class; syntactically it is a preposition phrase acting as a complement of *pick*. (What *kind* of complement will depend on which idiomatic sense of the *pick .. up* construction is intended.)

Comment: @StoneyB Well, it's a preposition and a preposition phrase. In the same way that a one-word noun can be a noun phrase. "Preposition" *is* just a word category, isn't it?

Comment: @Araucaria I think it's useful to distinguish the words--the write-outs or utterances--from the constituents, so I see it as a PP realized as a P.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a handle on it: *pick* is a verb and *up* is a preposition which has come to be understood as modifying the sense of the verb. Some grammarians will call the *up* a [particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle) instead of a preposition, but it's essentially a nonsense distinction that just means 'a preposition being used in this way'.

I don't understand what benefit you plan to get from having your parser treat the parts of phrasal verbs separately. Just treat *pick up* as a separate verb altogether and use coding to work around *pick ~ up* phrasing.

Comment: Well, initially the question came because I am trying to imagine how to distinguish between phrases like "pick lock" and "pick up flower". Which of course begs the question of how to distinguish between "pick flower" and those others. If there is a rule that modifies the meaning of "pick" based on possible conditions I need to know it to determine whether the functional verb is "pick" or "pick up".

Comment: When a noun is verbed 'it' (or rather the new intercategorial polyseme resulting) is called a verb, not 'a noun being used in this way'. The particles involved in multi word verbs have very distinct properties.